# Is it possible to automatically generate migration scripts by comparing db and code?

Tags: database, automation, liquibase, flyway

I’m seriously confused about how flyway generally works to maintain the db as a code. Suppose I have the following V0 script:

```
Create table student( 
  Name varchar(25)
)
```

That would be my initial db. Now, suppose I want to add a new column, why am I being forced to do a V1 script like this one?

```
Alter table student add column surname varchar(25)
```

What I’d like to do would be to simply update the v0 script like this:

```
Create table student( 
  Name varchar(25),
  Surname varchar(25)
)
```

Then the tool, by comparing the actual db, should be able to understand that a new column should be created!

This is as other code (java, javasctipt,..) tools work and the same I would it like to be for db as a code tools.

So my question is: is there a way to achieve this behavior without dropping/recreating the db?

I tagged this question with flyway and liquibase tools but feel free to suggest other tools that would fit my needs.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever way you develop the database,there is no way to achieve this behavior without dropping/recreating the db, because the CREATE TABLE statement assumes that the table that you specify isn't already there. You can't use a CREATE OR ALTER statement because these aren't supported for tables even where the RDBMS that you use supports that syntax.

In the early stages of a database project, you can work very much quicker with a build script that you use to create a database with tables, views and so on.  You can then insert some data, try it out, run a few tests, maybe and then tear it down. Flyway community supports this: you just have a single migration script starting from an empty database that you repeatedly 'clean' and 'migrate', until you reach your first version. Flyway takes care of the 'Tear-down' process. and give you a fresh start, by wiping your configured schemas completely clean.

Flyway Teams supports a special type of migration, the 'repeatable' that allows you to use for migrations SQL files that you can alter. However, you would need to add logic that deletes the table if it already exists  before it executes your CREATE TABLE statement. It avoids having to 'Flyway clean', but it is a lot of extra work. It also means that you lose the whole advantage of a version representing an exact state of a database.

At some  point, you are going to use migrations because you're likely to have copies of the database to keep up-to-date. Whatever tool you use to update a development or producton database, you are going to need to use a migration for this because of the existing data in tables.

Flyway Enterprise supports the automatic generation of a migration, if you are using Oracle or SQL Server. SQL Compare is provided to compare two versions of a database and produce a migration script from one version to the next. This allows you to use a build script as you suggest, compare it with the current version of the database, and generate a migration script to get from the one to the other.